# Get form date difference

Tags: php, html, get, datepicker

I have a html form with two inputs

```
<input type="datetime" name="start" id="start" ></input>
<input type="datetime" name="stop" id="stop" ></input>
```

And a `send.php` which mails me the form content.

In the **send.php** I want to calculate the difference in days between STOP and START, as in difference = STOP - START. If the difference between times is positive and bigger than 1 HOUR, then I want one extra day to be added.

```
If START = 02/01/2014 14:58:21
If STOP = 07/01/2014 14:59:21
```

Then output = 5 days

```
If START = 02/01/2014 14:58:21
If STOP = 07/01/2014 14:59:21
```

Then output = 6 days

How could I achieve this?

The `send.php` should send by mail the result.

So in my `.html` I have something like

```
<form action="send.php" method="get">

<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
<input type="datetime" name="START" id="START" ></input>
<span class="add-on">
<i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
</span>
</div>

<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
<input type="datetime" name="STOP" id="STOP" ></input>
<span class="add-on">
<i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
</span>
</div>
</form>
```

And my `send.php` is

```
<?php
@$pfw_ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

@$START= $_GET['START'];
@$STOP= $_GET['STOP'];
@$email= addslashes($_GET['email']);

$_start = new DateTime($_POST['start']); // or new DateTime($_POST['start']);
$_stop = new DateTime($_POST['stop']);// or new DateTime($_POST['stop']);
$interval = $_start->diff($_stop);

$to = "me@me.com";
$subject = "Calculator";
$headers = "From: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: $email\r\n";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$message = "<html><body style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:14.5px;\">";
$message .= " result between $STOP and $START is ....days
ID: $pfw_ip  <br/>";
$message .= "</body></html>";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>


the error i get now is Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateInterval could not be    converted to string in
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP >=`5.3`

Use this:

```
$_start = new DateTime('02/01/2014 14:58:21'); // or new DateTime($_POST['start']);
$_stop = new DateTime('02/05/2014 14:58:21'); // or new DateTime($_POST['stop']);
$interval = $_start->diff($_stop);
echo $interval->format('%a days'); // Should output "4 days".

//for (-)ve and (+)ve values, use:
echo $interval->format('%R%a days'); // Should output "+4 days".
```

So, in your send.php should look like this:

```
<?php
   $pfw_ip= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   $email= addslashes($_GET['email']);
   // Calculating the difference
   $_start = new DateTime($_GET['start']); 
   $_stop = new DateTime($_GET['stop']); 
   $interval = $_start->diff($_stop);
   // Preparing email content
   $to = "me@me.com";
   $subject = "Calculator";
   $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
   $headers .= "Reply-To: $email\r\n";
   $headers .= "Return-Path: $email\r\n";
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
   $message = "<html><body style=\"font-family:Calibri; font-size:14.5px;\">";
   $message .= " result between $STOP and $START is ".$interval->format('%R%a days')." 
   ID: $pfw_ip  <br/>";
   $message .= "</body></html>";
   mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Many kind thanks, but then if i put this code in the HTML form i will need to pass $interval as a variable to the send.php how do i do this? Plus datetime1 and datetime2 are two input fields, so i cannot declare them as static...

Comment: Assign a variable to it, something like `$diff = $interval->format('%a days');` You can then pass `$diff` variable to your send.php. As for your other query, I have added codes in the comments next to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot ohhmee for the help. There is still a bug. Now i get Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct() [<a href='datetime.--construct'>datetime.--construct</a>]: Failed to parse time string (22/01/2014 15:30:18) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character' in /home/site/public_html/send.php:4 Stack trace: #0 /home/site/public_html/send.php(4): DateTime->__construct('22/01/2014 15:3...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/site/public_html/sende.php on line 4

Comment: many kind thanks again for the help, i really appreciate trying to help me. For future reference if you are interested i have some projects on which we could work together, you could add me on facebook https://www.facebook.com/cristina.anghel.716195?ref=tn_tnmn

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is to convert the dates into a unix timestamp

```
$start = strtotime($_POST['START']);
$end =  strtotime($_POST['END']);
$interval = $end - $start;
```

because the answers are in seconds, you can do simple 
math to get the number of days

```
$days  = $interval / 86400 // number of seconds in a day
```

you can also see if the dates are within an hour

if ($interval > 3600), and so on

Comment: my form uses the get method and if i add in the send.php $stop= strtotime($_POST['stop']); it returns a blank

Comment: replace $_POST, with $_GET or $_REQUEST, which works with both